# why is my xml Query not working

Tags: xml, xslt, querying

i need to query from a XML file (that i include  here) 
[Link towards the xml file](https://prod-c2g.s3.amazonaws.com/db/Winter2013/files/courses-noID.xml)

i need to find all the courses that have the Prerequisites of a course given by a proferssor that called 'Eric'

Expected Query Result:

1. Programming Abstractions
2. Computer Organization and Systems
3. Introduction to Probability for Computer Scientists
4. Digital Systems II

i try to work in steps

I know i need to find all courses that have prerequisites CS106A and CS106B

so i try'ed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<Course_Catalog>
  <xsl:copy-of select="//Course[Prerequisites/Prereq = 'CS106B' and 'CS106A']/Title"/>
</Course_Catalog>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but this give's me

2. Computer Organization and Systems
3. Introduction to Probability for Computer Scientists
4. Digital Systems II

if i try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<Course_Catalog>
  <xsl:copy-of select="//Course[Prerequisites/Prereq = 'CS106A' and 'CS106B']/Title"/>
</Course_Catalog>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i only get

1. Programming Abstractions

so i can assume my "and" is not working?

Comment: You should not write about an "XML Query" (which sounds more like XQuery) - "XPath expression" is the correct term. In case you meant to refer to a whole code block above - that's called an _XSLT stylesheet_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit, re finding courses with Prof with First name as a Prerequisite**

You can use `xsl:key` to create an index lookup, and use this as a predicate into your template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="ProfLookup"
           match="//Course"
           use="@Number"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <CoursesWithPrerequsiteOfEric>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//Course[key('ProfLookup', 
          Prerequisites/Prereq)/Instructors/Professor/First_Name='Eric']"/>
    </CoursesWithPrerequsiteOfEric>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Course">
    <Course>
      <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
    </Course>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which spits out:

```
<CoursesWithPrerequsiteOfEric>
  <Course>Programming Abstractions</Course>
  <Course>Computer Organization and Systems</Course>
  <Course>Introduction to Probability for Computer Scientists</Course>
  <Course>Digital Systems II</Course>
</CoursesWithPrerequsiteOfEric>
```

**Edit**

Apologies for not grokking the original requirement first up. Your intermediate step is of course to find all courses which have 'CS106A' **or** 'CS106B' as prerequisites. But obviously the above key lookup solves the actual requirement.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <CoursesWithPrerequsiteOfEric>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="//Course[Prerequisites/Prereq = 'CS106A' or
                                         Prerequisites/Prereq = 'CS106B']"/>
 </CoursesWithPrerequsiteOfEric>
</xsl:template>
```

**Re : More Requirements**

Well, you can inline the key but it becomes harder to understand, IMO:

```
select="//Course[Prerequisites/Prereq = //Course[Instructors/Professor/First_Name='Eric']/@Number]"
```

And re counting - You'll need to brush up on your [xsl functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#aggregate-functions).

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//Course[Prerequisites/Prereq = //Course[Instructors/Professor/First_Name='Eric']/@Number])"/>
```

Comment: thanks for looking in my Question @StuartLC what i actualy need to do is find all courses that have a prereq of a course given by a professor by the name of Eric this will be <Prereq>CS106A</Prereq> and <Prereq>CS106B</Prereq> and in total this wil give a result of 4 course's (SEE : Expected Query Result)

Comment: that worked nice @StuartLC , only i need to do it without the key future and my last step would be to get a value so my last step would be to Count? my course/title to get   <Course_Catalog>4</Course_Catalog>

Comment: @taine updated, and welcome to StackOverflow. In future, please state the question in full up front - e.g. the limitations on the permissable syntax, and also avoid adding new requirements (like count) afterwards. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, for the solution @StuartLC , @ the point of creating this i was thinking to complete this step by step  still i am **happy** with you're input towards completing this question